# How to create custom SwiftUI View playground template in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-playground, xcode-template

I want to create a custom Xcode playground template for SwiftUI View.
What file formats are used?
How can I find examples?
Where should I put those files?

Answer (score 0):

You can make template by duplicating file templates at path

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Playground`

> Note that each platform has it's own templates.

1. Copy two folders `TEMPLATE_NAME.xctemplate` and `TEMPLATE_NAME___FileMenu.xctemplate`
   to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates` and rename them as you want.

(you can put it in subfolder `SwiftUI`, it's name will be used to separate your templates from others)
[image]

2. To change the displayed name of template you can change `Name` field in `TemplateInfo.plist`
3. Paste the code of your template into `___FILEBASENAME___.playground` file (you can use placeholders to generate code base on parameters, see for example this [article](http://jeanetienne.net/2017/08/27/xcode-template.html))

Here are my templates as an example: https://github.com/DanSkeel/XcodeTemplates/tree/main/Playground

> Note: `...___FileMenu.xctemplate` files will be used when you create new file from opened playground.