# Creating Custom SwiftUI Template File

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

I am currently working on my first project with SwiftUI. I use a lot of swift files and then I do some housekeeping before I even start coding. Unfortunately, it takes up a lot of time and I even make mistake while trying to create sections for my codes. So I am wondering if there is a way to create a custom template file that once I create the Marks (as seen on screenshot)[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F60bx.png) are already pre-written aside from using custom snippets. Thanks in advance and I hope this makes sense.

Comment: See This Link: https://johncodeos.com/how-to-create-custom-xcode-file-templates-using-swift/ or just search how to create xcode file templates

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. And yes I did do a search on how to create a custom Xcode file. Unfortunately I wasn't quite sure of what I was looking for yet until you came along. I figured that this community would be a little more enthusiastic in helping beginners. Thanks again.

Comment: I a bit related, I have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64507158/991816) about playground templates